# Rental property taxes income cap 2018

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

Current tax code for single and married is $150,000 income. Did they raise the amount cap you can make for married couple to write off a loss for our rental property for 2018? We make more and we’re told we can’t deduct anything for the rental home. The married income amount should reflect two incomes.

Comment: $150k for married, $75k for single. Are you asking for current filing purposes (tax year 2017) or planning for 2018 filing?  Also, the phase-out uses modified adjusted gross income (MAGI) not income.

Comment: @HartCO It's $150k whether married filing jointly or single (for some reason).

Comment: @CraigW Ah, it's MFS that's $75k, my whoops.

Answer (score 1):

No, the $100K - $150K phaseout hasn’t changed. Keep in mind, the losses get carried over, and will benefit you when the property is running at a profit.

Comment: Worth noting that carried over losses also benefit you when you sell.